# Why is this question not considered spam?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags

When reviewing in the First Posts Queue I came upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50327883):

> **WHAT ARE THE MAIN CLASSICAL REFERENCE BOOKS OF AYURVEDA HERBAL PLANT?**
>
> There are several books are available i.e Charak Samhita, Susrut
>   Samhita, Astang Hridaya, Sharangdhar Samhita, Madhav Nidan, Kashyap
>   Samhita, Bhavprakash and Bhaisajya Ratnavali

Since it doesn't have anything to do with programming and isn't even a real question but just an enumeration of authors I flagged it as spam. To my surprise this flag was declined with

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Why is this not considered spam?

**Sidenote:** the question later was put on hold with the reason

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...

which I find a bit inappropriate for a question not about programming.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I didn't handle the original flag, but deleted it as spam when I reviewed it from your post here. We cannot reverse the disputed flag.

It is spam, it was an incorrect flag handling. From the outset it appears to be completely off topic and the close voters have looked at the request for a book as a request for resource.  But the username, which is also part of the organisation being spammed, is also used in the question.

Sometimes these things happen, we all make mistakes. Don't let a  disputed or declined flag put you off flagging.

Comment: Is there a way to change it from "declined" to "disputed" retroactively, or am I mistaken? (I agree with marking this as spam BTW).

Comment: @EJoshuaS unfortunately no, it only works from marking them as helpful, then clearing them from the post, which stops them from being used as examples in an audit will then mark the flags as disputed. It's a shame declined flags cannot be reversed, but then it goes to development time and is it important enough.

Comment: Such rejections should be automatically reversed when the question gets deleted/put on hold, as this shows the flags were appropriate and the rejection was in error.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yes I agree with you about that. I should make it clear I was referring to the facility for mods to manually reverse a declined flag

Comment: "Don't let a declined flag put you off flagging." Sure, except that's *exactly what declined flags are meant to do*. This should absolutely be addressed by the devs in charge of the mod-tools.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy declined flags are supposed to teach flaggers how to flag, sometimes mistakes happen.

Comment: So if a scenario similar to what happened to the OP where to occur to us. What would our best course of action be then? Should we also post it on meta?

Comment: what was the original post? it's deleted now