# Why is this question not seen as spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, declined-flags, spam

I have been on Stack Overflow for a few months now, and yesterday I [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743238/redirect-original-page-but-page-must-use-as-iframe-for-embededing-if-open-this-p).

Now I get that the question of this user is about iframes, but they are referencing twice to a site which seems to be a streaming site. The linking itself seems unnecessary to me, so to me it came across as spam. I didn't click the links to verify, but the link looked tricky enough to me already.

It seems like the question entered [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19957614) and it was completed with
3x Requires editing and 1x Unsalvagable, after I flagged this post as spam. I noticed my flag then got disputed.

By now I am uncertain if I have followed the right procedure by flagging this as spam. Why isn't this seen as spam? Is it because nothing on the profile links to the said site?

If this is considered spam and I notice my spam flag gets disputed/declined, what is the right course of action after that?

I have also found this question on Meta: [Why is this question not considered spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367918/why-is-this-question-not-considered-spam) , but it didn't really answer my question.

Comment: FWIW, you'll see this sort of thing occasionally for HTML/CSS/JavaScript questions because new users who don't read the help think that including a link to the site they're working on is the same as providing the code. They don't know the rules require the code be in the question itself and it doesn't occur to them that the question will be useless once they fix their site (or it does but they don't realize we consider that a problem).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Outwardly, it doesn't look like the **intent** of the post is to promote a product or service. Outwardly, it looks just like a low quality question of someone trying to embed an iframe into his website and not providing any of the necessary steps for SO to help them (MCVE, their code, what they tried, etc).

I'm not sure I'd flag this as spam. Assuming good faith it's probably just a low quality question. That only marginally changes how it should be treated anyways. As it's currently sitting at -2 and is well on track to being closed, the question is most likely going to suffer automatic deletion in due time.

Comment: That is a really clear explanation. So in nearby future, it is best for me to flag these kind of questions as low quality?

Comment: @Codeer Or as to be closed. In this case unclear and too broad and maybe another couple of reasons fit. The key to look out for when deciding to flag something as spam or not is if the post was created just to advertise or and not that someone is linking to a sketchy website because that's the object of their question.

Comment: Summed it up better than I did. Thanks Magisch. Really pleased to see you active again.